# Make a parent div inherit sibling Height?

Tags: html, css

I'm lookign for a way to make a parent container div inherit its siblings height which is set to auto is this possible? i know you can do it the other way round.

Thanks again.

Comment: Can you show some specific HTML, and CSS, that allows us to reproduce the problem you're trying to solve? And explain precisely what that problem is, and what you want?

Comment: I have not cleared any floats and I never set heights on my container or content divs, The problem is I never could fully grasp the concept of Css positioning. I have divs positioned off page, that are inside and relative to a container div. Below of which is a footer, but the container will not inherit the height of the content divs.  I cant really post an example unfortunatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way a DIV can inherit a sibling height -without JavaScript- would by using using a table in HTML or table display properties in CSS.

```
.outerDiv{
display: table
}
.innerDiv{
display: table-row
}
.siblingDiv{
display: table-cell 
}
```

Update as requested. I have done it in JQuery as it's easier. I haven't tested it yet but it should work, just change identifiers to suit how your DIVs are identified.

JQuery:

```
$(function(){ var setheight = ('.contentDiv ').height(); ('.containerDiv').height(setHeight) });
```

Goodluck

Comment: I see, thats rather frustrating. All I need to do is push the footer to the bottom of the content, but to do this I need the container div to inherit the height of the content div.  :/ Do you know the javascript solution?

Comment: Check Answer for update. I have done it in JQuery instead of JavaScript though.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the parents css to have

```
overflow: auto;
```

and remove any preset max-heights etc, it will then be responsive and take the childs height.

I think this is what you are asking?

Comment: Not quite, I already have a overflow of hidden set to a container div because im hiding divs off screen. Setting the overflow to auto just crushes the content knocking my document flow out of whack.

Answer (score 1):

By default, a parent container will stretch to contain any child elements. Without seeing your HTML and CSS, I can't diagnose your problem. Take a look at things like not clearing your floats (you should), or setting a height on your parent container (you shouldn't).

Comment: I have not cleared any floats and I never set heights on my container or content divs, The problem is I never could fully grasp the concept of Css positioning. I have divs positioned off page, that are inside and relativew to a container div. Below of which is a footer, but the container will not inherit the height of the content divs.